# Mysql full text searches match() filter specific symbol

Tags: mysql, filter, match, symbols

I'm trying to use `MATCH()` to do full text searches.

But this sql is error.

```
SELECT id FROM `unit` WHERE MATCH('![(][)][)]');
```

I search '!())' , but the execute is error. so i don't konw how to filter the specific symbol.

Comment: Are you sure you have used correct syntax for `Match()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't MySQL `MATCH()` require an `AGAINST()` clause?

See [Natural Language Full-Text Searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) and [Full-Text Search Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) for specifics.

**Edited to add:**

The OP comments that he's using Sphinx, which makes a *significant* difference. [This page](http://astellar.com/2011/12/replacing-mysql-full-text-search-with-sphinx/) talks about getting started with Sphinx, including an example of using `MATCH()` without `AGAINST()`.

But I have to add that the OP's example looks what he really wants to use is a [regular expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html), which is something else again.

Comment: I was also thinking for the same :) but just a bit late to point

Comment: if I use sphinx. So How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You have search `!())` but from which column try this one

```
SELECT id FROM `unit` WHERE MATCH('![(][)][)]') AGAINST(your column name to match);
```

Also make sure you have added `FULLTEXT` index to the column

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD FULLTEXT ft_title (your column name to match);
```

Comment: sorry, I forget to tell you, I use sphinx . And so I execute the sql in sphinx db. e, maybe I don't understant the sphinx. pardon me. thanks.